Possible MSVC C++17 bug while initializing std::string alternative in std::variant with string literal
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

void f(std::variant<bool, std::string> v) {
  if (std::holds_alternative<std::string>(v))
    std::cout << "std::string\n";
  if (std::holds_alternative<bool>(v))
    std::cout << "bool\n";
}

int main() { f("str"); }

MSVC cl.exe /std:c++17 outputs
bool

Other compilers and MSVC cl.exe /std:c++20 output
std::string

Is this MSVC C++17 known issue?
https://godbolt.org/z/3WEPjnjjv

See this post. To be checked if this was implemented retroactively or not, but long story short: MSVC is, or at least used to be correct in C++17 mode.
